# How to redirect http to https and www to non-www via web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, https, web-config

I would like to use web.config to redirect all requests on my asp.net site to https:// with non-www. That is:

```
http://
http://www
https://www
```

should all go to

```
https://
```

So far I have this for my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
...
 <rewrite>
   <rules>
     <clear />
     <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url=".*" />
       <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
     </rule>
   </rules>
 </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The above snippet takes care of redirecting these two:

```
http://
http://www
```

But I'm missing the last, which is:

```
https://www  --->  https://
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add second rule:

```
<rule name="NonWwwRedirect"  stopProcessing="true"> 
    <match url="(.*)" /> 
    <conditions> 
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.sitename\.com$" /> 
    </conditions> 
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://sitename.com/{R:1}" /> 
</rule>
```

You just need to replace `sitename.com` with your domain name

Comment: Old post I know. I'm trying to do a http --> https as well as a www --> non-www. Should the `action url="http://......."` not be `action url="https://...."`? Since the OP was wanting https redirect as well?

Comment: In .NET Core 3.1 in every client I receive ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 3):

Here´s a generic rule that worked for me:

```
<rule name="Force non-WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:2}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Should be upvoted many more times. Generic rule much better than the accepted answer which can be found dozens of times on SO.

Comment: This does not answer the question as where is HTTPS?